# Can I insert named captures in the Match tree without actually matching anything?

Tags: grammar, raku

I was curious if I could insert things into the Match tree without actually anything. There's no associated problem I'm trying to solve.

In this example, I have a token `market` that checks that its match is a key in the hash. I was trying to then insert the value of that hash into the match tree somehow. I figured I could have a token that always matches, `long_market_string`, and then look into the tree somehow to see what `market` had matched.

```
grammar OrderNumber::Grammar {
    token TOP    {
        <channel> <product> <market> <long_market_string> '/' <revision>
        }

    token channel    { <[ M F P ]> }
    token product    { <[ 0..9 A..Z ]> ** 4 }

    token market     {
        (<[ A..Z ]>** 1..2) <?{ %Market_Shortcode{$0}:exists }>
        }

    # this should figure out what market matched
    # I don't particularly care how this happens as long as
    # I can insert this into the match tree
    token long_market_string { <?> }

    token revision   { <[ A..C ]> }
    }
```

Is there some way to mess with the `Match` tree as it is being created?

I could do something that inverts things:

```
grammar AppleOrderNumber::Grammar {
    token TOP    {
        <channel> <product> <long_market_string> '/' <revision>
        }

    token channel    { <[ M F P ]> }
    token product    { <[ 0..9 A..Z ]> ** 4 }

    token market     {
        (<[ A..Z ]>** 1..2) <?{ %Market_Shortcode{$0}:exists }>
        }
    token long_market_string { <market> }
    token revision   { <[ A..C ]> }
    }
```

But, that handles that case. I'm more interested in inserting an arbitrary number of things.

Answer (score 1):

Tokens are a type of method, so if you wrote a method that did all of the setup work that a token does for you, you could do almost anything.

This is not specced, and is currently not easy.
( I only have a vague idea of where to start looking in the source code to figure it out )

---

What you can do easily is add to the `.made`/`.ast` of the result
( `.made` and `.ast` are synonyms )

```perl6
$/ = grammar {
  token TOP {
    .*
    {
      make 'World'
    }
  }
}.parse('Hello');

say "$/ $/.made()";  # Hello World
```

It doesn't even have to be inside of a grammar

```perl6
'asdf' ~~ /{make 42}/;
say $/;     # ｢｣
say $/.made # 42
```

---

Most of the time you would use an Actions class for this type of thing

```perl6
grammar example-grammar {
  token TOP {
    [ <number> | <word> ]+ % \s*
  }
  token word {
    <.alpha>+
  }
  token number {
    \d+
    { make +$/ }
  }
}

class example-actions {
  method TOP    ($/) { make $/.pairs.map:{ .key => .value».made} }
  method number ($/) { #`( already done in grammar, so this could be removed ) }
  method word   ($/) { make ~$/ }
}

.say for example-grammar.parse(
  'Hello 123 World',
  :actions(example-actions)
).made».perl

# :number([123])
# :word(["Hello", "World"])
```

Comment: This isn't close to what I'm asking, really. All of that is easy. I want to insert other things into the match tree that don't have tokens. You can't "do almost anything" because the Match objects have immutable bits.

Comment: @briandfoy An Int is also an immutable object. When I said a token is a type of method, I mean it inherits from Method, and adds a bunch of things. If you do that bunch of things yourself in a regular method you can do absolutely everything a token can do. I don't plan on spending a week or more looking at the source code to do something that almost no-one needs to do. I have tried to do this very same thing several times before you asked, and didn't think it was worth the time after spending hours on it.

Comment: Okay, but I already know that and wasn't debating that. You said you tried the same thing (I guess implying that you couldn't get it done), but it also sounds like you're trying to convince me it's trivial to do on my own. Mixed messages there.

Comment: @briandfoy I had other interests to look into that were more interesting to me at the time, and much easier to do.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to subvert the match tree into doing something the match tree isn't really supposed to do. The match tree tracks what substrings were matched where in the input string, not arbitrary data generated by the parser. If you want to track arbitrary data, what's wrong with the AST tree?

Sure, in one sense the AST tree has to mirror the parse tree, since it's constructed in a bottom-up fashion as the match methods complete successfully. But the AST itself, in the sense of "the object attached to any given node" is not so restricted. Consider for example:

```
grammar G {
    token TOP { <foo> <bar> {make "TOP is: " ~ $<foo> ~ $<bar>} }
    token foo { foo {make "foo"} }
    token bar { bar {make "bar"} }
}
G.parse("foobar");
```

Here `$/.made` will simply be the string "TOP is: foobar" while the match tree has child nodes with the components that were used to construct the top-level AST. If then return to your example, we can make it:

```
grammar G {
    my %Market_Shortcode = :AA('Double A');
    token TOP    {
        <channel> <product> <market>
        {} # Force the computation of the $/ object. Note that this will also terminate LTM here.
        <long_market_string(~$<market>)> '/' <revision>
        }

    token channel    { <[ M F P ]> }
    token product    { <[ 0..9 A..Z ]> ** 4 }

    token market     {
        (<[ A..Z ]>** 1..2) <?{ %Market_Shortcode{$0}:exists }>
        }

    token long_market_string($shortcode) { <?> { say 'c='~$shortcode; make %Market_Shortcode{$shortcode} } }

    token revision   { <[ A..C ]> }
    }

G.parse('M0000AA/A');
```

`$<long_market_string>.ast` will now be 'Double A'. Of course, I'd probably dispense with `token long_market_name` and just make the AST of `token market` whatever is in `%Market_Shortcode` (or a Market object with both short and long name, if you want to track both at once).

A less trivial example of this kind of thing would be something like a grammar of Python. Since Python's block level structure is line-based, your grammar (and thus match tree) need to reflect this in some way. But you can also chain several simple statements together on a single line by separating them with semi-colons. Now, you'll probably want the AST of a block to be a list of statements, while the AST of a single line may itself be a list of several statements. Thus you'd construct the AST of the block by (for example) `flatmap`ing together the list of the lines (or something along those lines, depending on how you represent block statements like `if` and `while`).

Now, if you really, really, *really* want to do nasty things to the match tree I'm pretty sure it can be done, of course. You'll have to implement the parsing code yourself with `method long_market_name`, the API for which is undocumented and internal, and will likely involve at least some dropping down into nqp::ops. The stuff pointed to [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl6/comments/5naomy/where_can_i_start_looking_to_speed_up_regular/) will probably be useful. Other relevant files are `src/core/{Match,Cursor}.pm` in the Rakudo repo. Note also that the stringification of Matches is computed by extracting the matched substring from the input string, so if you want it to stringify usefully, you'll have to subclass Match.

Comment: The AST tree is what I'm trying to subvert. But, there really isn't an AST. There's a tree of match objects that have a key called "ast" that aren't connected directly. The AST is forced to have the same structure as the Match tree.

Comment: “The AST is forced to have the same structure as the Match tree” huh?

Comment: The AST lives in Match objects.

Comment: The AST lives in match objects, but if you need to insert something where you match nothing, there's nothing stopping you from having an empty match which generates an AST (like in `token long_market_string` above). The purpose of the match tree is to track what rules matched what where; keeping track of what all of this *means* to your program is the business of the AST.